# Uniqueness of rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Suppose we have a rational complex function:

$$G(z)=\frac{a_n z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+a_1 z+a_0}{b_m z^m+b_{m-1}z^{m-1}+\dots+b_1 z+b_0}$$

And now we consider only its evaluation on the complex axis $z=i\omega$, $H(\omega)=G(i\omega)$.

$\bullet$ Does exist any other complex function $\hat G(z)$ such that its complex axis evaluation $\hat H(\omega)=\hat G(i\omega)$ satisfies
$H(\omega)=\hat H(\omega)$ and $G(z)\neq\hat G(z)$ ?

$\bullet$ If it exists, does $\hat G$ need to be a rational function too?
And lastly:

$\bullet$ Has this any relation to the method of analytic continuation? I mean if the fact that we know $G$ on the real axis lets us continuate its domain of definition to all the complex plane (except at its poles).

Comment: Do you mean $H(y) = G(iy)$ ? In this case $H$ is a complex function of a real variable.

Comment: No I don't mean that. I mean that if by knowing the evaluation of $G$ in $z=i\omega$ it is possible to determine $G$ over all the complex plane.

Comment: I assume that you also mean for $\hat G$ to be analytic? If so, the answer is no, by the standard theory of analytic continuation. Otherwise, the answer is yes, and trivially so.

Comment: Hi @Harald Hanche-Olsen, I'm not an expert at all in complex analysis. I wonder I you could expand your answer. Is it true that rational functions are analytic? In any case I don't mind if the function is analytic or not.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, rational functions are analytic! Sorry I don't have the time to go into great detail however. Maybe someone else can pitch in.